# Getting an ACK failure right away after writing slave address in interrupt mode [STM32F401RE]

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, bare-metal, stm32f4

I see that once slave address is written in the interrupt handler, I get an ACK Failure right away, but when I do the same thing with polling approach, I do get an ACK and goes on to read off the values from the device.

With interrupts, I see ISR gets triggered only once (in which it writes slave address) and never gets called again. My i2c configurations are fine, but there's something with interrupts that I seem to be missing out on.

**Polling approach**

```
HAL_Status I2C_HAL_TX_IT () {
            GenerateStartCondition();

            // validate the completion of start condition   
            while (!GetFlagStatus(hi2c->Instance, I2C_SR1_SB) && HAL_Timeout(5));

            // write slave address along with write bit
            I2C_WriteSlaveAddress(hi2c, WRITE);

            // wait for address to be sent
            while (!GetFlagStatus(hi2c->Instance, I2C_SR1_ADDR) && HAL_Timeout(5));

            // clear address flag
            I2C_ClearADDRFlag(hi2c->Instance);

            // write data to DR ...
}
```

**With interrupts:**

```
void HAL_StartI2CInterrupts() {
     GenerateStartCondition();

    // setting control bits
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN;
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN;
    hi2c->Instance->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_ITERREN;
}

void I2C1_EV_IRQHandler () 
{

    uint8_t event_interrupt = (hi2c->Instance->CR2 & I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN) >> I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN_Pos;

    uint8_t buffer_interrupt = (hi2c->Instance->CR2 & I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN) >> I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN_Pos;

    uint8_t var;

    if (event_interrupt)
    {
        //  validate the completion of START condition
        var =  (hi2c->Instance->SR1 & I2C_SR1_SB) >> I2C_SR1_SB_Pos;
        if (var)
        {
            if (hi2c->I2C_State == I2C_TX_BUSY)
            {               
                I2C_WriteSlaveAddress(hi2c, WRITE);     
            }
        }
         // check ADDR bit ...
     }

}
```

Comment: what does the scope show for each approach?

Comment: are you referring to register values for each approach? @old_timer

Comment: what do the I2C signals look like on the scope, does one approach look any different than the other and does the peripheral actually ack?

Comment: This where the i2c transaction stops for interrupts. https://imgur.com/a/prxEeXl
For polling, I see an ACK and goes onto generating the STOP condition...in other words, that works! @old_timer